# 2 random vectors in multidimensional array

Tags: matlab

I am trying t odo this:

```
weights = rand(64,1); % creates an array with 64 initial weights
weights(:,2) = rand(40,1); % creates an array with 40 initial weights
```

As the code explains: fill the first vector with 64 random values and then do the same with the second vector and put them into the same variable. So I am abel to access them as so:

```
weights(:,1) % <-- will display entire first vector
weights(:,2) % <-- display entire second vector
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this, because the first call creates a matrix with `size(64,1)`. Therefore, all columns must have `64` rows, instead of your `40`.

You can use cells instead, e.g.

```
weights{1} = rand(64,1); % creates an array with 64 initial weights
weights{2} = rand(40,1); % creates an array with 40 initial weights
```

and use them like

```
weights{1}
weights{2}
```

However, if this solution is useful for you depends on what you want to do else with the data.

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution to using cells like Nemesis pointed out is structures, e.g.:

```
weights.a = rand(64,1);
weights.b = rand(40,1);
weights.a, % <-- will display entire first vector
weights.b, % <-- will display entire second vector
```

I personally think the cells solution Nemesis mentioned is more useful but I guess it depends on what you're doing with it.